# Mysql Server performance using php/exec or php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, exec, shell-exec

### What is better ( in performance/response ) regarding PHP/mysql requests please:

- Using normal mysqli library
- Using exec('mysql -u user -pPassword database -e "request" 2>&1 ')

By the way I'm not caring about the server RAM but about the server CPU, 
I want a fast answer to the user and I need your advice for that.

Thank you

Comment: Never use "exec('mysql -u user -pPassword database -e "request" 2>&1 ')". I won't even go into all the problems it brings. Let's just call it a giant security hole

Comment: What are you asking about? I don't understand why you would want to use either one of them.

Comment: Euhene, yes I'm aware about the security so this will be handled later on.

Comment: Dharman, My question is about performance.
So actually, mysqli create server connection then make request. Exec execute the request directly into mysql, no server communication. its a direct request like you are executing a program or a shell script with params.
The response with exec will be instant, the response with mysqli will be like data streamed by server.

Comment: @MohamedMetoui It's not really a question of performance. Even if you manage to get the proposed idea working, which is not a given considering return values of exec, the security hole implications of this are just to big. The time and resources spent on developing protection for this thing will be huge. Any "possible" performance that you could have "possibly" gained you will loose so much more developing protection for this. Php was not developed by fools - use the instruments that go with the language.

Comment: Also, I would imagine that executing requests through shell would be 100x slower. I absolutely see no reason to use `exec`. I would also advise not to use mysqli. Do not use mysqli, but use PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the library (mysqli or PDO).  Period.  Full stop.

The `exec` needs to do

1. Launch a process (on client)
2. Start up `mysql` (on client)
3. Connect to mysql (both client and server)
4. Prepare and execute the request (mostly server)
5. Disconnect (both)
6. shutdown the process (on client)

And that achieved performing only one "request"

With `mysqli`:

1. Connect to mysql once (both)
2. Prepare and execute many requests (one at a time) (mostly server)
3. disconnect once (both)

That is, instead of using CPU, RAM, I/O, etc for 6 steps to run one request, you are using those resources for connecting only once, not once per request.

That is, resources is *less* for the mysqli approach, at least when running multiple "requests".  And the client is definitely doing less work, even for a single request.

"no server communication" -- No.  That is not possible.  All the database work is always done on the server.  The client does little more than send requests and receive results.

`mysql` is a *client* program.  `mysqld` is the *server*.  They are different.  Think of `mysql` as a standalone program that has a library equivalent to "mysqli" builtin.